# Bash adding line with criteria

Tags: bash, line

I have a reference file with only one column that goes like this:

file1:
a
b
c
d
e

In a second csv file I have several column. In the first of these column there are some of the value present in the reference file:

file2:
a;34;42;23;45;1
c;3;2;1;7;8
e;6;2;2;1;3

What I would like to obtain is to add the lines that are present in file1 but not in file2 with constant value for some column and zero in the last column, so to have:

a;34;42;23;45;1
b;cost1;cost2;cost3;cost4;0
c;3;2;1;7;8
d;cost1;cost2;cost3;cost4;0
e;6;2;2;1;3

Any help?,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
( cat file2  ; comm -23 file1 <(cut -d';' -f1 file2) \
| sed 's/$/;cost1;cost2;cost3;cost4;0/' ) | sort
```

to put it in the script copy the following text in it:

```
( cat file2  ; comm -23 file1 <(cut -d';' -f1 file2) | sed 's/$/;cost1;cost2;cost3;cost4;0/' ) | sort
```

or even more adopted for human version:

```
( 
    cat file2
    comm -23 file1 <(cut -d';' -f1 file2) | sed 's/$/;cost1;cost2;cost3;cost4;0/' 
) | sort
```

Comment: This is ok, it will allow to go through all the line.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus . But how to put this in a script, and not on the command line? I'm getting `syntax error near unexpected token ('` when lunching the script. But works in the command line.

Comment: @g256 i added another variants that can be easily copy&pasted.

Comment: I'm still getting an syntax error near unexpected token . Could it be because I'm executing it inside a for loop for diffent file like: for i in *file; do; your code; done

Comment: I edited to avoid scrolling. You can join the lines to form one line, and make sure you remove the line continuation '\' characters.

Comment: for i in file*
do
(
     cat ${i}  
     comm -23 ctry <(cut -d';' -f1 ${i}) | sed 's/$/;cost1;cost2;cost3;cost4;0/ 
 ) | sort > h${i}
done

Comment: looks like missing newlines or `;` and last `'` is also missing. try this one: `for i in file* ; do ( cat ${i} ; comm -23 ctry <(cut -d';' -f1 ${i}) | sed 's/$/;cost1;cost2;cost3;cost4;0/' ) | sort > h${i} ; done`

Comment: What shell do you use? Try to replace `(` to `{` next way: `for i in file* ; do { cat ${i} ; comm -23 ctry <(cut -d';' -f1 ${i}) | sed 's/$/;cost1;cost2;cost3;cost4;0/'; } | sort > h${i} ; done`

Comment: Or even absolutely without `(`: `for i in file* ; do { cat ${i} ; cut -d';' -f1 ${i} > ${i}.tmp ; comm -23 ctry ${i}.tmp | sed 's/$/;cost1;cost2;cost3;cost4;0/'; rm ${i}.tmp ; }  | sort > h${i} ; done`. This is may occur because your shell doesn't support subshells redirections which is used in `<(cut -d';' -f1 ${i})`.

Comment: @Rush Ok, this did the job.Thanks. But I notice that some line are added even if they are already present in file2. Any ideas?

Comment: That's strange. `comm` is case-sensitive. Can that issue make sense? If not, can you show the real example of data which doesn't work the way you're expect?

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS = OFS = ";"} FNR == NR {arr[$1] = $0; next} ! ($1 in arr) {print $1, "cost1;cost2;cost3;cost4;0"} END {for (i in arr) {print arr[i]}}' file2 file1
```

The output will be in an undefined order (except that all the new lines will be printed first). If you are using GNU AWK (`gawk`) and you need the lines to be sorted, you can save the new lines in the array instead of printing them immediately and use the `asort()` function. Otherwise, you can use the external `sort` utility.

Broken out on multiple lines:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {
        FS = OFS = ";"
    } 
    FNR == NR {
        arr[$1] = $0; 
        next
    } 
    ! ($1 in arr) {
        print $1, "cost1;cost2;cost3;cost4;0"
    } 
    END {
        for (i in arr) {
            print arr[i]
        }
    }' file2 file1
```

**Edit:**

To accommodate multiple lines in file2 with the same field 1, change this line:

```
        arr[$1] = $0;
```

to

```
        arr[$1]
```

and add this line immediately after it:

```
        lines[$0]
```

Then change these lines:

```
        for (i in arr) {
            print arr[i]
```

to

```
        for (i in lines) {
            print i
```

**Edit 2:**

To print the added line 10 times with different values change this section:

```
    ! ($1 in arr) {
        print $1, "cost1;cost2;cost3;cost4;0"
    }
```

to

```
    ! ($1 in arr) {
        for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            print $1, "cost1", i, "cost3;cost4;0"
        }
    }
```

Comment: This works really well. The only problem is that in file2 each line can be repeated more than one. So for example more than one line with a or c or d. And with this code at the end just one line will be report for each value. Hope this is clear. Thanks a lot anyway. This was really useful.

Comment: @g256: That condition was not specified in the question. Please see my edited answer for changes that should accommodate it.

Comment: Slightly change: If I would like to insert the missing lines let's say 10 times with 10 different constant in the position of const2? (of course for all the missing line) would this be difficult? Thanks for support.